# macOS: Get Safari to show web page load progress bar in full screen mode

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, fullscreen

It's annoying to hover over the Menu bar or Toolbar of Safari to see if my click is being responded, or how much of the next page has loaded in when running Safari in full screen mode.

How can I get a thin strip of progress bar? I don't want a Toolbar. I don't want Tab Bar. Just a Progress Bar.

I am running Safari 12 on macOS Mojave 10.14.

**Note**: If there's no native solution for this, I am willing to install 3rd party extensions too. Something similar to in-page progress indicator used on websites such as Medium or YouTube.

Sample Progress bar on Medium:

[image: Sample progress bar on medium]

Comment: Are you referring to the webpage load progress indicator? It is shown in the unified address and search bar.

Comment: yes I am referring to that webpage load progress indicator. I want it to be displayed separately on each webpage load while I am in full screen mode and Toolbar and Tab-bar are hidden, i.e. true full screen mode.

Comment: The progress indicator is shown as a part of address bar. If you have chosen to hide the Toolbar in the full-screen mode, where are you expecting to see the progress bar? Most likely, you are looking for a 3rd party Safari extension which can achieve the desired.

Comment: Please See the edit. The green bar on the top

Comment: Did you tried searching for one here: https://safari-extensions.apple.com ?

Comment: Yes. Couldn't find any. Such extensions from Firefox extension centre have been removed.